# Change UIViewController to UIView

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xcode4.2

I am new at iOS development,

I want to draw a line in my app, i created a simple viewbased application,

I came to know that for drawing a line we require `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method, but this method is available in `UIView` not in 
 `UIViewCOntroller`

How to change my class to `UIView` ?

Here is my code snippet,

```
// .h file
@interface Financial_Calc : UIViewController{
    UIButton *firstBtn,*secondBtn;
}
 @end

//.m file
@implementation Financial_CalculatorViewController

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSLog(@"drawRect");
}

@end
```

**Any help will be appreciated**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the view controller you have, and make a custom view class for it to control.

1. Choose File > New File…
2. From iOS, Cocoa Touch, Choose 'Objective-C Class', Click Next
3. Name your class 'MyView' (or anything you like, the convention is to have view at the end)
4. Make your class a subclass of UIView (type UIView in the 'subclass of' field)
5. Click next, choose a location to create the file (anywhere in your project's folder is fine).
6. Add your custom drawing code to `drawRect:` in MyView.m
7. In your view controller's Xib file, select the view.
8. Choose View > Utilities > Show Identity Inspector
9. In the 'Custom Class' field, change the class field from 'UIView' to 'MyView'
10. Build & run - your view controller is now controlling your custom view.

It's also possible to do this without using the user interface Xib, but this should get you going.

Comment: upto 6 point your suggestion is working but on 7th point i am unable to see my `MyView.xib` file there is only 2 file `MyView.h` and `MyView.m`

Comment: That's the view controller Xib file, not the view. Based on your code snippet, it's probably named `Financial_CalculatorViewController.xib`. If you don't have one, you may have started with a different template, or used Storyboards?

Answer (score -1):

**FYI: you cannot change UIViewController to UIView.** One way to do is, create a new subclass of UIView (lets say called CustomUIView). there do your coding of draw rect. and in your ViewController.m in viewDidLoad method create an object of CustomUIView Class (lets say customUIView) and do this

```
[self.view addSubView:customUIView];
```

Comment: no idea who downvoted but maybe because the correct function to change the baseview of a viewcontroller  would be `loadView`